# Oracle SQL How to skip an update that reaches an specific timeout?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I'm running a query that has a loop, but in one of its iterations it gets stuck because some other process is trying to update the same row (or some other reason). How can I have the update skip that iteration & continue with the next?

Comment: Give more details about what tools or languages you are accessing the DB from.  The DB has some generic settings such as resource profiles, but there "client side" settings that may be applicable, for example to set timeouts for the Oracle Net layer, or explicit 'callTimeout' options in some Oracle DB drivers.

Comment: "Skip-and-continue"? To the best of my knowledge there's no way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more details this is really hard to answer. But the general approach would be to lock the rows before starting the process that updates them and skipping any already locked rows.

Something like this:

```
select ...
from the_table_to_update
where ...          --<< your conditions go here
for update nowait  --<< lock the rows, but don't wait for a lock
skip locked;       --<< ignore already locked rows.
```

The loop over the result of that query (e.g. through a cursor or in your programming language)